# Why doesn't \write work when nothing is typeset in document?

Tags: write

I can't understand at which point `\openout` opens files, `\write` writes to them and `\closeout` closes them. I find that if nothing is typeset in the document environment, only the immediate writes write anything, and only if all of `\openout`, `\write` and `\closeout` are preceded by `\immediate`. If only some of `\openout`, `\write`, `\closeout` are not preceded by `\immediate`, things are more complicated and sometimes the file is created but is left empty (so the buffer is not flushed and the file is probably not closed). Here's a MWE of what I've discovered:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\wpreim
\immediate\openout\wpreim=test_pre_immed.txt\relax
\immediate\write\wpreim{FOO}
\immediate\closeout\wpreim

\newwrite\wpredel
\openout\wpredel=test_pre_delayed.txt\relax
\write\wpredel{FOO}
\closeout\wpredel

\immediate\write18{echo FOO >> test18_pre_immed.txt}
\write18{echo FOO >> test18_pre_delayed.txt}

\begin{document}
% case 1: having nothing typeset in the document: only the immediate write's write
% case 2: having some content (e.g. ~) in the document: all of the write's until the last \eject write
% case 3: having nothing typeset after the last \eject: only the write's until the last \eject write
~
\vfil\eject

\newwrite\wdocim
\immediate\openout\wdocim=test_doc_immed.txt\relax
\immediate\write\wdocim{FOO}
\immediate\closeout\wdocim

\newwrite\wdocdel
\openout\wdocdel=test_doc_delayed.txt\relax
\write\wdocdel{FOO}
\closeout\wdocdel

\immediate\write18{echo FOO >> test18_doc_immed.txt}
\write18{echo FOO >> test18_doc_delayed.txt}

\end{document}
```

Call it foo.tex, check with

```
rm test*.txt ; pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex ; for i in test*.txt ; do ls -l $i ; cat $i ; done
```

Comment: try with `\immediate\openout`

Comment: @touhami That was it, I edited my comment to reflect this. I'd still like a more thorough explanation of why I see what I see: does everything in the whatsit "buffer" get discarded if there is no new page shipped?

Comment: I don't think it really gets *discarded*. It just sits there, as I understand it from the TeX Book.

Comment: `\immediate\closeout` not necessary unless you need to input the file. In your example you used `\openout...` and `\immediate\write...`  so you immediatly write to some thing does not exist yet.

Comment: @touhami Ah, that's why I see it on the terminal (and it the log), I just read in "TeX by Topic" that if I \write to a file that isn't opened, it is not an error, rather it goes to the screen/log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\immediate\write` writes to the output stream immediately, but `\write` on its own doesn't write anything it puts the tokens into a whatsit node that is saved in the current vertical list along with boxes and glue from the document text and the actual write happens at `\shipout` as a page is written to the dvi or pdf file (so page numbers are correct) so if you do not ship out a page containing the vertical list that includes that whatsit node, the saved information is never used.

Comment: And this applies to \openout as well? I see that putting \immediate on \write and \closeout but not on \openout still does not create the file, while putting \immediate on \openout and not on \write creates it but leaves it empty.

Comment: @AaylaSecura yes openout and closeout can be delayed or not the same as \write so if you delay the open but do an immediate write that won't work.